# CookieContainer не получает все данные

Tags: c#, http

Здравствуйте.
Есть файл login.php и он возвращает следующие данные:

> `Заголовки ответа
> Server  QRATOR
> Date    Tue, 08 Jan 2013 16:07:48 GMT
> Content-Type    text/html
> Transfer-Encoding   chunked
> Connection  keep-alive
> Keep-Alive  timeout=15
> Set-Cookie  sid=deleted; expires=Mon, 09-Jan-2012 16:07:47 GMT pl_id=deleted; expires=Mon, 09-Jan-2012 16:07:47 GMT PHPSESSID=aafa0361b4d2a66a9d1e36b1dc8e8e22; path=/; HttpOnly pl_id=4198923 duration=13660; expires=Tue, 07-Jan-2020 16:07:48 GMT sid=68e8a5a259e554319f32f1252338d758
> Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
> Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
> Pragma  no-cache
> Location    home.php`

Так вот, моя процедура:

```
string data = "login=" + login + "&pass=" + password + "&LOGIN_redirect=1&lreseted=0&preseted=0";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(siteUrl);

request.Method = "POST";

request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; rv:15.3) Gecko/20121203 Firefox/15.3.2-x64 PaleMoon/15.3.2-x64";

request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";

request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
byte[] EncodedPostParams = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(data);
request.ContentLength = EncodedPostParams.Length;
request.GetRequestStream().Write(EncodedPostParams, 0, EncodedPostParams.Length);
request.GetRequestStream().Close();

CookieContainer authInfo = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer = authInfo;

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

authInfo = request.CookieContainer;
```

Получает только **PHPSESSID** а мне обязательно нужно получить еше и **pl_id**?
В чем проблема?

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Покажи, как ты парсишь ответ сервера.

Comment: вот:
cookieBox.AppendText("Cookie IN LOGIN.PHP\n");
            StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder(String.Empty);
            
            foreach (var str in authInfo.GetCookies(st))
            {
                msg.Append(str);
            }
            cookieBox.AppendText(msg.ToString());
            //

            string html = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)).ReadToEnd();
            showInfoBox.AppendText(html);

Comment: И что ты получаешь в **msg** и **html**?

Comment: в msg я получаю одну строку в которой мне отображается phpsessid и все, а в html если отключить переадресацию то небудет ничего, а если включить то мне выдаст хтмл код главной сраницы поскольку я буду на нее перенаправлен так как произошла ошибка авторизации изза того что нет pl_id!

Comment: Вот еще результат работы программы: http://s57.radikal.ru/i157/1301/3d/f6e58ff2b141.png
Тоесть с login.php парсится только PHPSESSID а нужно еще и pl_id.

Comment: это я так понимаю продолжение вопроса) куки pl_id является httponly. то есть значение нельзя прочитать напрямую. тем не менее этот куки должен содержаться в cookiecontainer при получении, если не ошибаюсь. (хотя и невидим для функции GetCookies к примеру)

Comment: то как мне тогда получить pl_id. Просто для того, чтобы мне сжелать следующий заарос - как раз этот параметр и нужно передавать.

Comment: попробуйте просто передать полученный CookieContainer. Мне кажется HttpOnly cookie автоматом включаются в запрос..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Об этой проблеме много написано в инете. Мне лично ни одно решение не подошло.
Советую Вам вместо HttpWebRequest использовать класс System.Net.Sockets.Socket.
По крайней мере в похожей битве за куки мне помогло именно применение сокетов.

З.Ы.
Надо передавать все куки:
sid=deleted;
pl_id=deleted;
PHPSESSID=aafa0361b4d2a66a9d1e36b1dc8e8e22;
pl_id=4198923 duration=13660;
sid=68e8a5a259e554319f32f1252338d758
иначе POST нормально не пройдет.
+ заметьте, сервер отдает 2 pl_id (pl_id=deleted и pl_id=4198923), а в этом случае по RFC не определено, что именно будет принято клиентом.